# $\log \inf_{x\in \partial U} f_x(z)=\inf_{x\in \partial U} \log f_x(z)$?

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $U$ be an open set of $\mathbb{C}$. Fix $x\in \partial U$. Define $f_x(z)=|z-x|$. Is the following true?
>
> $\log \inf_{x\in \partial U} f_x(z)=\inf_{x\in \partial U} \log f_x(z)$.

My try:

$\log \inf_{x\in \partial U} f_x(z)\leq \log f_x(z)$. Hence $\log \inf_{x\in \partial U} f_x(z)$ is a lower bound for $\{\log f_x(z); x\in \partial U\}$. So, we have $\log \inf_{x\in \partial U} f_x(z)\leq\inf_{x\in \partial U} \log f_x(z)$. But I could not show the other direction. So I can't decide whether the statement is true or false. Can we actually prove the equality? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a complex analysis problem: it's asking whether the inf operation on sets of real numbers is preserved under the log transformation.

So let $A$ be a set of real numbers, and let $h$ be a monotonically increasing continuous function. We claim: If $h$ is continuous at $\inf A$, then
$$h\left(\inf A\right) = \inf\left\{ h(x): x\in A\right\}$$

Proof: Write $a:=\inf A$. As you've shown, $h(a)$ is a lower bound for $h(A):=\left\{ h(x): x\in A\right\}$. To show $h(a)$ equals the inf of $h(A)$, it suffices to show that we can find points of $h(A)$ arbitrarily close to $h(a)$. Let $\epsilon>0$. Since $h$ is continuous, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|h(x)-h(a)|<\epsilon$ whenever $|x-a|<\delta$. Since $a$ is the inf of $A$, there exists $x\in A$ such that $a\le x<a+\delta$. This implies
$$
h(a)\stackrel{(1)}\le h(x) \stackrel{(2)}< h(a) + \epsilon\tag{*}
$$
where (1) follows from the fact that $h$ is monotonically increasing, and (2) follows from continuity of $h$. And we're done!

The proof only requires continuity of $h$ at $a$. There is some fussiness for $h(x):=\log x$ if $a=0$; a different argument is required in that case.

Comment: Is it possible to prove the statement without continuity?

Comment: @Soke Without continuity of $h$, the statement may be false. For example define $h(x)=x$ if $x\le0$, $h(x)=x+1$ if $x>0$. Take $A:=(0,1)$. Then $\inf A=0$ but $\inf h(A)=1\ne0= h(\inf A)$.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks